# Multiple Interfaces with Metadata access in MEF?

Tags: c#, interface, mef

I have created three interfaces:

```
interface A
{
  B obj{ get; }
}

interface B
{ 
  C obj { get; }
}

interface C { }

[Export(typeof(C))]
class class C1 : C
{ 
  //.........
}


[Export[typeof(B)]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "ABC")
class class1 : B
{
  [Import(typeof(C))]
  public C Cvalues;

  public C obj
  {
    get { return Cvalues; }
  }
}

[Export(typeof(B))]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "XYZ")]
class class2 : B
{
  [Import(typeof(C))]
  public C Cvalues;

  public C obj { get { return Cvalues; } }
}
```

Now, I want Export metadata of interface B in interface A

```
[Export(typeof(A))
class AA : A
{

  // how i get the B here
  [Import(typeof(B)]
  public B Bvalues;

  public B objB { get { return Bvalues; } }
}
```

If i try to create the property of interface B in interface A then at one import of B it's give me output but what about ImportMany because interface B returns ImportMany...

Please give me some idea how can I get my all interface B exports in interface A.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata can be imported using a `Lazy<T, TMetdat>` instance. In simple terms this means:

```
[Import(typeof(B))]
Lazy<B, IDictionary<string, object>> _b;

public B ObjectB { get { return _b.Value; } }

public string NameB { get { return _b.Metadata["Name"]; } }
```

But, often it is a good idea to define a metadata contract, e.g.:

```
public interface INameMetdata
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Which you can use instead of the dictionary:

```
[Import(typeof(B))]
Lazy<B, INameMetadata> _b;

public B ObjectB { get { return _b.Value; } }

public string NameB { get { return _b.Metadata.Name; } }
```

Using metadata contracts will enable you to use a statically-typed interface implementation, that MEF will automatically project for you.

Comment: not understand your idea please describe something more in detail

Comment: I try to implement you logic but not working. on about logic i can able to call single component in Lazy but when more then one component in extension directory Lazy not take the Component. it's not give any error but internal process not happen. if you give some proper demo then please give here. tested demo is more good for guding. Thank you

Comment: @user166694 If you want to import more than one component use an ImportMany on a property of type `IEnumerable<Lazy<B, INameMetadata>>`

Comment: @Daniel : i do that think but with Lazy<B,IDirectory<stringg,object>>
but not getting the export part in Lazy. what is meaning of INameMetadata. please explain in detail.